# SpreadJS not working in Webpack based angular application

Tags: c#, angular, webpack, .net-core, spreadjs

I am trying to add the **spreadjs** library to my Angular 5 application. I am following the tutorial given in this link. 
https://www.grapecity.com/en/blogs/spread-sheets-and-angular
But one difference is there between the tutorial and my application. My app is using webpack.

When I am trying to run the application I am getting the following error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: GC is not defined
>       at Object. (gc.spread.sheets.angular.11.0.4.js:106)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 05add16ed08b4def07f8:657)
>       at fn (bootstrap 05add16ed08b4def07f8:85)
>       at Object. (app.module.browser.ts:21)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 05add16ed08b4def07f8:657)
>       at fn (bootstrap 05add16ed08b4def07f8:85)
>       at Object. (index.js:4)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 05add16ed08b4def07f8:657)
>       at fn (bootstrap 05add16ed08b4def07f8:85)
>       at Object.options.path (html5-entities.js:190) (anonymous) @ gc.spread.sheets.angular.11.0.4.js:106
>   **webpack_require** @ bootstrap 05add16ed08b4def07f8:657 fn @ bootstrap 05add16ed08b4def07f8:85 (anonymous) @
>   app.module.browser.ts:21
>   **webpack_require** @ bootstrap 05add16ed08b4def07f8:657 fn @ bootstrap 05add16ed08b4def07f8:85 (anonymous) @ index.js:4
>   **webpack_require** @ bootstrap 05add16ed08b4def07f8:657 fn @ bootstrap 05add16ed08b4def07f8:85 options.path @ html5-entities.js:190
>   **webpack_require** @ bootstrap 05add16ed08b4def07f8:657 fn @ bootstrap 05add16ed08b4def07f8:85
>   **decorate @ main-client.js?v=m6MAq5LYDxHuj3aQ3FLsDASzSdE0PXrpCFP8K7zsieI:4472
>   __webpack_require** @ bootstrap 05add16ed08b4def07f8:657 module.exports @ bootstrap 05add16ed08b4def07f8:706 (anonymous) @
>   bootstrap 05add16ed08b4def07f8:706

I tried adding  the javascript link to **webpack.config.vendor.js**. My backend is .net core webapi. Please advice me what to do next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

This is likely the result of not importing some required scripts in the `angular.json` file. This is a step that the default SpreadJS instructions  GrapeCity's website (https://www.grapecity.com/en/blogs/spread-sheets-and-angular) are lacking for current Angular applications.

I found this missing step on one of GrapeCity's Angular/SpreadJS blogs (https://www.grapecity.com/en/blogs/create-angular-spreadsheets-with-angular-cli) , which was a little hidden on their site.

The step you need is:

**angular.json:**

```
{
  (…)
  "apps": [
    {
      (…)
      "styles": [
        "./lib/gc.spread.sheets.excel2013darkGray.11.0.0.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "./lib/gc.spread.sheets.all.11.0.0.min.js"
      ],
      (…)
    }
  ],
  (…)
}
```

Change the filepath to wherever you placed your SpreadJS files. Note that at least in my app, my `angular.json` files has two `styles` arrays and two `scripts` arrays - insert these references into the top set (the styles and scripts array closest to the top of the `angular.json` file).